# What's the cleanest functional-programming style way to perform this list operation?

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style

I am looking for the correct method for accomplishing the unknown piece in the following code snippet:

```
rolls = Tuples[Range[1, 4], {2}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, 
> {3, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 1}, {4, 2}, {4, 3}, {4, 4}}
> ```

```
Tally[rolls, Min[#1] == Min[#2] &]
```

> ```
> {{{1, 1}, 7}, {{2, 2}, 5}, {{3, 3}, 3}, {{4, 4}, 1}}
> ```

```
(*Unknown List Manipulation Code*)
```

> ```
> (1*7 + 2*5 + 3*3 + 4*1)/Length[rolls]  
> (*where previous result is of the form {{{a, b}, c}, ...}
> the numerator is the sum of Min[a,b]*c for every item in the list that is the previous result*)
> ```

I can imagine some very complex solutions, but I suspect that there is an elegant functional solution that I am missing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
rolls = Tuples[Range[1, 4], {2}];
tally = Tally[rolls, Min[#1] == Min[#2] &];
lis = {{{1, 1}, 7}, {{2, 2}, 5}, {{3, 3}, 3}, {{4, 4}, 1}}
Total[Min@#[[1]]*#[[2]] & /@ lis]/Length[rolls]
```

Which gives:

> `15/8`

Comment: All of these answers are useful, but this one best matches what I was looking for.

Answer (score 12):

Is this what you want?

```
Min /@ Tuples[Range[1, 4], {2}] // Mean
```

> ```
> 15/8
> ```

Pinguin Dirk forced me to post this:

```
f[n_, k_] := Range[n, k].Reverse@Range[1, 2 (k - n + 1), 2]/(k - n + 1)^2
```

it appears to be 10 times faster than:

```
Plus @@ Times @@@ Transpose@{##, Range[2 Length[#] - 1, 1, -2]
                            }/Length[#]^2 &@Range[50, 10000] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.010001, 100500125/29853}
> ```

```
f[50, 10000] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.001000, 100500125/29853}
> ```

Comment: @Kuba: forced you? :) But I like the implementation! I was just inspired by other Q&As where people discuss how to avoid `Tuples` and its friends (and this was an easy one). Nice work

Comment: @PinguinDirk I totally agree, but you know: "let's test Kuba's solution... 1000 times slower". I had to respond :p

Comment: @Kuba: I took yours cause I like it best! But a good challenge is always welcome, more will come!

Comment: @PinguinDirk Indeed, it's the motor of the progress. :) and hank you, I'm glad you like it.

Answer (score 11):

If it should be functional programming style, try this:

```
Plus @@ (Min @ #1  #2& @@@ {
  {{1, 1}, 7}, {{2, 2}, 5}, {{3, 3}, 3}, {{4, 4}, 1}})/Length[rolls]
```

> ```
> 15/8
> ```

Answer (score 9):

You want the sum of `Min[a, b] c` for every `{{a, b}, c}` in the list? You can quite literally do that.

```
rolls = Tuples[Range[1, 4], {2}];
tally = Tally[rolls, Min[#1] == Min[#2] &];
numerator = Total[tally /. {{a_, b_}, c_} :> Min[a, b] c]
result = numerator/Length[rolls]
```

Comment: What does the :> operator do? Could you link me to the documentation page?

Comment: @Techrocket9 it's called RuleDelayed, you can just type :> in mathematica and hit F1 to get the documentation

Answer (score 6):

**I am assuming a sorted list as input - else `Sort` it first**

Looking at the problem you want to solve, I suggest **not** to use `Tuples`, as this will get slow, the more rolls you have. So here's a way to solve it without `Tuples`, but rather basic combinatorics:

```
 Plus @@ Times @@@ Transpose@{##, Range[2 Length[#] - 1, 1, -2]}/Length[#]^2 &@Range[4]
```

> `15/8`

To compare speed, I chose the nice solution of @Kuba, using `Range[5,10000]` (explicitly another starting point, to see if solutions agree) (note: `Range[5,10000,2]` etc also works)

```
Plus @@ Times @@@ Transpose@{##, Range[2 Length[#] - 1, 1, -2]}/
   Length[#]^2 &@Range[50, 10000] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> `{0.006532, 100500125/29853}`

```
Min /@ Tuples[Range[50, 10000], {2}] // Mean // AbsoluteTiming
```

> `{6.524025, 100500125/29853}`

Comment: Ok, I've posted something faster than `Tuples` :)

Comment: you win :) @Kuba

Comment: I think the case is still open :) Thanks for the kick.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using `GroupBy[]`:

```
Total[KeyValueMap[Times, GroupBy[rolls, Min, Length]]]/Length[rolls]
   15/8
```